# Grouping cases on certain criterion

Tags: spss, data-transformation, group-differences

You experts have been helpful so many times that I read others' threads, but this time I have to ask a new question.

Long story short I need to *group all my cases into 4 categories*. Could someone please help me figuring out the procedure in spss?

(I have individuals' scores on 2 variables - fashion innovativeness and fashion opinion leadership - and other data which is irrelevant to my question)

*Fashion innovators* - persons scoring more than one standard deviation above the mean on fashion innovativeness but less than one SD above the mean on fashion opinion leadership. 
*Fashion opinion leaders* - persons scoring more than one SD above the mean on fashion opinion leadership but less than one SD above the mean on fashion innovativeness. 
*Innovative communicators* - persons scoring more than one SD above the mean on both fashion innovativeness and fashion opinion leadership.
*Fashion followers* - persons scoring less than one SL above the mean on both fashion innovativeness and fashion opinion leadership.

How do I create groups with these conditions? I need that in order to give a demographic profile of each group and compare them on certain traits.

Sorry, I am truly on bad terms with spss. Thanks much for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it would help us a lot if you'd call your variables simply v1 and v2 and the groups just 1 throught 4. The verbosity in these descriptions renders your question rather hard to read.

OK, I won't discuss the methodological soundness of the reasoning but purely technically you need to do two things.

1) Run [AGGREGATE](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/aggregate/) with `MODE ADDVARIABLES` and no break variable to create the two means and two SD's in your data. Note that you can create all four variables in a single `AGGREGATE` command.

2) Run four `IF` statements to create the groups. They'll look something like

if v1 gt mean_v1 + sd_v1 and v2 lt mean_v2 + sd_v2 group = 1.

This will first create a new variable `group` (make sure it doesn't exist yet) and initialize the values for all cases to [SYSTEM MISSING](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/missing-values/#sysmis). Next, for cases whose score on `v1` is higher than the mean on `v1` + one SD on `v1` but whose score on `v2` is lower than the mean on `v2` + one SD on `v2`, `group` will get the value `1`. You can create the `IF` statements for the other three groups in a similar vein, probably assigning values 2 through 4.

Last, apply proper [VALUE LABELS](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/changing-variable-properties-5-variable-and-value-labels/#vallabs) to these values.

Comment: Hi Ruben! Sorry for messiness of my question. And thanks a lot for your reply. This will help! :)

Comment: @desperate-about-statistics: no worries! Just a suggestion for improvement. I'll write a brief tutorial on these `IF` statements too since many users seem unaware of them. I'll let you know when it's done if you like. If anything else is not (entirely) clear, let me know, we're obviously still developing the site and feedback is appreciated!

Comment: hey Ruben, that would be great if I was notified about a tutorial on this topic. Thanks a lot! What's you're doing is great

Comment: @desperate-about-statistics: thanks! I finished a gentle tutorial on [using IF in SPSS](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/if/). Hope you find it helpful.